# .map() undefined is not a function in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Right, I'm probably missing the obvious here but I am getting an 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' I seems to be .map() that's the problem but I can not see why.

```
var idealist = React.createClass({
loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.props.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            this.setState({data: data});
        }.bind(this)
    });
},
handleButtonClick: function(input) {
    // do stuff //
},
getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
},
componentWillMount: function() {
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
},
render: function() {
    var clickFunction = this.handleButtonClick;
    var ideas = this.state.data.map(function(i){
        return <ideabox data={i} onButtonClick={clickFunction} />;
    });
    return (
        <div className="idealist">
            {ideas}
        </div>
        );
}
});

React.renderComponent(
<idealist  url="/json/quotes.php"  pollInterval={2000}/>,
document.getElementById('quoteList')
);
```

If I change it to 
    var ideas = this.state.data
I don't get any errors, the JSON data is formatted correctly, what can be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that this.state.data is an array?

Comment: [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a function on JavaScript's Array; it's not defined by React. Make sure `this.state.data` is an Array.

Comment: Thats why I'm confused, state, as far as I'm aware has to be an array and state.data is defined in getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
},. state.data is updated by loadCommentsFromServer. The script in question is returning properly formatted JSON data

Comment: `state` is always an Object, not an Array. Can you paste a sample return value from the Ajax call. My only guess is `data` is not an Array in the JSON response.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It was a stupid mistake, quotes.php wasn't returning properly formatted JSON data so it wasn't an array .map() was being called on. The lesson learnt? Don't take other people word for it that their code works!

Answer (score 6):

`.map()` is a method that create a new Array with results that are provided.

Here is the documentation for that:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

The thing that you can do here would be to change the `.data` property of the object to return an Array. Since the `.map()` would work on Array type objects only.

Comment: Actually, `map` works on any array like object, but you need to set the `this` value explicitly via `.call` or `.apply` or duck type it.

Answer (score 3):

if this helps any one, another easy to overlook error is to initialize the variable to an empty object instead of an empty array in the state and calling map().

for example, declaring below

```
const [list, setList] = useState({});
```

instead of

```
const [list, setList] = useState([]);
```

and trying to call map() on the object

```
list.map((item)=>{
    //do something
})
```

will lead to "undefined is not a function near ... list.map(..." error during load of the component

Comment: Thank you very much